# Unable to deploy a JSF project with Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, jsf, glassfish

I've been using Eclipse Kepler with Java 1.7, Glassfish 4 and JSF 2.2 successfully for a while. I've just installed Eclipse Mars, the latest version, and installed Java 1.8_66, and got a simple "Hello World" test to run in the console mode. After downloading Glassfish 4.1.1, the latest version, I set up a simple "Hello World JSF" project, but I'm unable to associate it with the server. On right clicking on the Glassfish server in the server window and selecting "Add and Remove", I keep getting the message:

"There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server."

On right clicking on the project then selecting Properties > Project Facets, everything appears to be in order, and have the following selected:

Dynamic Web Module 3.1,
Glassfish Web Extensions 4.0,
Java 1.8,
JavaScript 1.0, and
JavaServer Faces 2.2,

which is identical to the setup I had with Eclipse Kepler, except for the version of Java, and as far as I know, there is no Glassfish Web Extensions 4.1. What is going wrong, and how to I associate the project with the server?

Glassfish is running normally, and get the greeting page at localhost:8080 when I start it manually using asadmin start-domain in the console. However, if I start it from Eclipse, I get the following text in the Eclipse console:

Starting preview server on port 8080

2015-12-25 19:01:41.539:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1285ms
2015-12-25 19:01:41.793:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
2015-12-25 19:01:42.173:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@3bcacab5{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-12-25 19:01:42.177:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1931ms

with the last four lines in red. When I go to localhost:8080 I get the message:

Error 404 - Not Found
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

so the server is obviously running, but doesn't pick up the HTML in the default page. This is presumably related in some way to why I cannot get anything linked with Glassfish in Eclipse.

Some ideas on what is happening and how to fix this would be very welcomed indeed, as I really want to upgrade to the latest versions of Eclipse, Java and Glassfish.

Comment: Can you check the context of the project? Usually the url will be http://localhost:8080/your-project-context

Comment: Thanks, but I can't even get as far as that.  Eclipse says that there are no resources to add to the server, so I can't even start.  The faces-config.xml, glassfish-web.xml and web.xml all appear to be good, and are the same, as far as I can see, as with JSF projects in Eclipse Kepler, except of course for the project names.

Comment: I had problems in Mars until I had only 8 jdk and jre on my pc/eclipse

Comment: I just fixed the problem and got a simple "Hello World JSF" message displayed at localhost:8080/<project-name>.  After a lot of messing around, I found that Eclipse Mars had not been configured properly with Glassfish-4.1.1.  I had already installed Java 1.8 on my computer, and Eclipse worked previously with a console version of a "Hello World" test.